# My table to display the right side of the screen Not fit

Tags: android, layout, android-tablelayout

I want to display table in Fit the Screen, but I try to use below the code to divide into two parts of the screen and display in Right side only. What is my mistake? Like this why is not filling my screen?

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXZnk.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#282828"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#282828"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="DATE"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ColOrDate"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="ORDER DATE"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/order_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="NO"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ColOrNo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="ORDER NO"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/In_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="QTY"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Colorderqty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="ORDER QTY"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/created_date"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9.0"
                    android:text="RAW MAT"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ColRaw_mat"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9.0"
                    android:text="VENDOR NAME"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/out_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="BILL NO"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ColBillno"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="BILL NO"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/balan_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="REC DATE"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Colrecdate"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="RECEVIED DATE"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="REC QTY"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ColRecQty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="RECEVIED QTY"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="UOM"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Column"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4.0"
                    android:text="UOM"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

row_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#282828" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: show your row_border.xml

Comment: yes i update that @SathishKumarJ

Comment: i think you are posting wrong layout `xml` code. but your screen shot shows different. check screenshot and layout `xml`

Comment: No bro its Right Layout, just focus on Table Not above the buttons and others

Comment: but your xml starts with `DATE` Textview . in your screen shot contains some extra components

Comment: yes, its an another xml file . the problm in inside of table layout

Comment: your `TableLayout` is good. the problem is in your another xml

Comment: okay bro I will check it and come back

Comment: see my answer/screenshot of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `xml` has no problem. it's works as well as what you expect. see the `Screenshot`

[image: answer]

The problem may be in your another `xml` file